# Can I print content in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

Flash provides a simple way to print the contents. Is there a way to do the same in silverlight also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this in Onclick handler:

```
      window.document.execCommand("Print");
```

IE will bring up a print dialog to give options for printing

If that doesn't work I found a blog posted by someone that focuses on printing in Silverlight found here [here](http://jonas.follesoe.no/PrintingInSilverlight2UsingCSSAndASPNETAJAX4.aspx)

Comment: Is there any way I can set it to Landscape or Portrait via this method.